# When trying to add a div after each image element, all the divs are instead added after a single element

Tags: jquery

So I'm using jQuery to try and add a gradient div on top of each image with the class "radial-gradient".

I store all matched elements in an array:

```
var $imgRadialGradient = jQuery("img.radial-gradient");
```

For each element I wait until it has loaded and then calculate the height:

```
$imgRadialGradient.each(function(){

  $this = jQuery(this);

  $this.load(function() {

    var imgRadialGradientHeight = $this.height();
```

Then I add a div with with a few styles based on that height:

```
$this.after("<div class='radial-gradient' style='height:"+imgRadialGradientHeight+"px; margin-top:-"+imgRadialGradientHeight+"px'></div>");

  });

});
```

Problem is the divs are all getting added after the last element not after each element as I intend.

Here's a bin: http://jsbin.com/luqiluweje/3/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
$this = jQuery(this);
```

with:

```
var $this = jQuery(this);
```

Otherwise `$this` is a global variable, shared (and changed) by all iterations of the function. By the time any of the `load()` handlers are called, `$this` always points to the last image.

```js
var $imgRadialGradient = jQuery("img.radial-gradient");

$imgRadialGradient.each(function() {

  var $this = jQuery(this);

  $this.load(function() {

    var imgRadialGradientHeight = $this.height();

    $this.after("<div class='radial-gradient' style='height:" + imgRadialGradientHeight + "px; margin-top:-" + imgRadialGradientHeight + "px'></div>");

  });

});
```

```css
body {
  width: 400px;
}
div.radial-gradient {
  background-image: radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 1));
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg" class="radial-gradient">
<img src="http://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg" class="radial-gradient">
<img src="http://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg" class="radial-gradient">
```